# merge multiple columns to one column in SQL

Tags: sql, merge, hiveql

```
name       A.subject     A.grade
Michael     Math             69
Michael     Natural Sciences 43

name      B.subject    B.grade
Michael     History         99
Michael     Geography       23
```

to

```
name       subject         grade
Michael     Math             69
Michael     Natural Sciences 43
Michael     History          99
Michael     Geography        23
```

How could I achieve it in Hive SQL? Thanks....................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all`

```
select 
    name, 
    a.subject, 
    a.grade 
from yourTableA a
union all
select 
    name, 
    b.subject, 
    b.grade 
from yourTableB b
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Union ALL`

```
select name, A.subject, A.grade from tablename A
union all
select name, B.subject, B.grade from tablename B
```